# Is this a valid definition for main()

Tags: c, standards, language-lawyer, c11

The C11 Standard declares that:

> 5.1.2.2.1 Program startup
>
> 1. The function called at program startup is named main. The implementation declares no prototype for this function. It shall be defined with a return type of `int` and with no parameters:
>
>    ```
>    int main(void) { /* ... */ }
>    ```
>
>    or with two parameters (referred to here as `argc` and `argv`, though any names may be used, as they are local to the function in which they are declared):
>
>    ```
>    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }
>    ```
>
>    or equivalent; <sup>10)</sup>, or in some other implementation-defined manner.
>
> ---
>
> <sup>10)</sup> Thus, int can be replaced by a `typedef` name defined as `int`, or the type of `argv` can be written as `char ** argv`, and so on.

We will ignore this part: *or in some other implementation-defined manner.* since I'm interested only in definitions equivalent to the two above examples.

Would this be a valid definition for main since `char* a[4]` and `char**` are equivalent:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[4]){/*...*/}
```

How about a VLA array, we are assuming `printf` will return a positive int value:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[printf("Hello there!")]){/*...*/}
```

Comment: Please note that you are citing the section for _hosted implementations_. This section does not cover free-standing implementations.

Comment: I think it would be interesting to ask if `argv[static 4]` is also equivalent to these.

Comment: @GrzegorzSzpetkowski: Yes, since `static` doesn't affect the type. Of course, type qualifiers like `const` and `restrict` which can also be used this way do affect it.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is all covered by the "or equivalent". The footnote about renaming parameters or using `typedef`ed types are just examples.

My favorite variant is

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[argc+1]){/*...*/}
```

because it has the most information about the semantic of all `main` functions.

Answer (score 2):

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[4]){/*...*/}
```

is a valid signature of `main`. Compiler will ignore `4` in `char argv[4]` and it is equivalent to `char argv[] = char **argv`. Same goes with second signature.

Comment: Given that in C11 performing `typedef int FOO[printf("Wow");];` will execute the printf, even if no variables are declared as type FOO, is there anything in the Standard that specifies that the dimension of the array argument will not be evaluated, as opposed to being evaluated and the result ignored?

Comment: @supercat; Found nothing against it.

Comment: By that do you mean that the Standard would seem to permit such execution but does not specify that it occurs?  Does it say anything about the validity of `void foo(int x[-1])` or of calling `void foo(int length; int dat[length])` when `length <= 0`?  What about the effect of `void foo(int dat[x++][y++])` when `x` and `y` are global variables?

Comment: *Does it say anything about the validity of void foo(int x[-1])*: Yes. You will get compile error for this. What actually happen is that at compile time compiler will check whether after `[` there is a +ve number/value or not. If there is a +ve number (or value of an expression) or nothing is there then its fine otherwise it will raise an error.  `void foo(int length; int dat[length])` and `void foo(int dat[x++][y++])` is perfectly valid in C99 and latter. Read C11: Section 6.7.6.2 p4 and example 10.

Comment: By my reading of the Standard, defining a function as as `void foo(int dat[x++][y++]) {...}`  would require that if `y` is greater than zero before `foo` is called, a compiler must increment it (if `y` isn't greater than zero, the call is UB), but the compiler is required not to increment `x` nor place any requirements on its value?  Would that concur with your reading?

Comment: @supercat; I thought `x` and `y` have some value other than `0`. If `x` and `y` are global then C standard would not allow it to compile but there is GCC extension which allow zero length array.

Comment: If `y` is greater than zero *at the time of the call*, why should any zero-length-array extension be required?  My reading would be that given `int arr[720]; int x; int y=1;` at global scope, the first invocation of `foo(arr);` would regard `arr` as a pointer to a block of memory holding 720 single-element arrays, the second as a pointer to a block holding 360 two-element arrays, the third as a pointer to a block holding 240 three-element arrays, then 180 four-element arrays, 144 five-element arrays, and 120 six-element arrays.